# Serialize DateTime to XML in specific format .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, format

I have a large collection of automatically generated classes that are serialized to / deserialized from XML using .NET XmlSerializer. Some of those classes contain DateTime properties.

I have a requirement to serialize **all** DateTime properties using specific format, for example "u". :

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("u");
//returns something like "2008-06-15 21:15:07Z"
```

Deserialize method seems to work with this format, but serialization does not - it just gives me hardcoded format <s>same format as I have by default in the hosting system (maybe I can trick the serializer by changing thread setting?)</s> (check Update #1).

**Note:**
I've already checked few related questions and they are solved by modifying original properties and adding new ones. For me it is not acceptable due to large number of modification I'd have to make.

- [How to serialize Xml Date only from DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983302/how-to-serialize-xml-date-only-from-datetime-in-c-sharp)
- [Force XmlSerializer to serialize DateTime as 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534525/force-xmlserializer-to-serialize-datetime-as-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)

Below is a sample test class that I use to test this issue.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

namespace FunkyTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SerializationTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void FunkySerializationTest()
        {
            var date = DateTime.Now;
            var dummy = new Dummy() { DummyProperty = date };
            var xml = SerializeToXml(dummy);//serializes with "o" format

            var expected = date.ToString("u", new CultureInfo("en-US"));//in this example I want "u" format
            var actual = XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("DummyProperty").Single().Value;
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void FunkyDeserializationTest()
        {
            var date = DateTime.Now;
            var dummy = new Dummy() { DummyProperty = date };
            var xml = SerializeToXml(dummy);//serializes with "o" format
            var deserializedDummy = DeserializeFromXml<Dummy>(xml);

            Assert.AreEqual(dummy.DummyProperty, deserializedDummy.DummyProperty);
        }

        private static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string xml)
        {
            using (var textReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(textReader))
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    var result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    return (T)result;
                }
            }
        }

        private static string SerializeToXml<T>(T objectToSerialize)
        {
            var xml = new StringBuilder();
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(xml, new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
            {
                var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize, ns);
            }
            return xml.ToString();
        }

        public class Dummy
        {
            public DateTime DummyProperty { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Any funky ideas?

**Update #1:**
I thought that date serialization is dependent on Thread.CurrentCulture. If I interpret XmlSerializer code correctly, format is hardcoded (thank you ILSpy).

```
// System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCustomFormatter
internal static string FromDateTime(DateTime value)
{
    if (XmlCustomFormatter.Mode == DateTimeSerializationSection.DateTimeSerializationMode.Local)
    {
        return XmlConvert.ToString(value, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzzzzz");
    }
    return XmlConvert.ToString(value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind);
}
```

**Update #2:** I have added a test method that uses proposed answer from Alexander Petrov. It fails at assertion of Ticks. According to [Serialize DateTime as binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919598/serialize-datetime-as-binary) problem is in internals of DateTime and is caused by loosing "Kind" of DateTime. It was suggested to use DateTimeOffset, which leads to another problem of serialization, explained in [How can I XML Serialize a DateTimeOffset Property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377036/how-can-i-xml-serialize-a-datetimeoffset-property)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3534525/1997232) (which you already mentioned), you are limited to either `XmlIgnoreAttribute` (using another property of e.g. `string` type to serialize/deserialize `DateTime` property) or `IXmlSerializable` (custom serializer, where you can add own attributes, through which you can specify various options for serializer/deserializer including data format). If you can find culture-dependent `XmlSerializer` (I bet there should be one), then you can create own culture with custom `DateTime` format and use it.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use custom xml reader and writer.

```
public class CustomDateTimeWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public CustomDateTimeWriter(TextWriter writer) : base(writer) { }
    public CustomDateTimeWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding) : base(stream, encoding) { }
    public CustomDateTimeWriter(string filename, Encoding encoding) : base(filename, encoding) { }

    public override void WriteRaw(string data)
    {
        DateTime dt;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(data, out dt))
            base.WriteRaw(dt.ToString("u", new CultureInfo("en-US")));
        else
            base.WriteRaw(data);
    }
}

public class CustomDateTimeReader : XmlTextReader
{
    public CustomDateTimeReader(TextReader input) : base(input) { }
    // define other required constructors

    public override string ReadElementString()
    {
        string data = base.ReadElementString();
        DateTime dt;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(data, null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dt))
            return dt.ToString("o");
        else
            return data;
    }
}
```

Use

```
var dummy = new Dummy { DummyProperty = DateTime.Now };
Console.WriteLine(dummy.DummyProperty);
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dummy));
string xml;

using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
using (var xmlWriter = new CustomDateTimeWriter(stringWriter))
{
    xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

    xs.Serialize(xmlWriter, dummy);
    xml = stringWriter.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(xml);

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
using (var xmlReader = new CustomDateTimeReader(stringReader))
{
    dummy = (Dummy)xs.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    Console.WriteLine(dummy.DummyProperty);
}
```

**Advantages:**

This approach automatically (de)serializes all values of the date-time to/from the desired format, without requiring changes to the generated classes.

**Disadvantages:**

This approach can accidentally change the values like date-time.

This approach might slow down the (de)serialization.

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting. I have updated my test to use your serialization method, And it fails with a strange message: Result Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<2016-08-25 14:21:58>. Actual:<2016-08-25 14:21:58>. Most probably there's a problem with Ticks. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Instead of WriteRaw use WriteString. That worked for me.